# How to put ASM source code comments in comment window of OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, ollydbg

I have the source code of an assembly language program, which has comments on every line, and I want to see those comments in the comment column of OllyDbg's disassembly as it debugs. Without writing a full blown plugin, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experience I found that there are basically 3 approaches:

1. Modify the .udd files that OllyDbg uses to store comments directly.
2. Use a label plug (unfortunately the one I found does not work on 2.01)
3. Create a debug file in a format OllyDbg understands (DWARF I think)

Since 3 is pretty complex, my best option is probably 1.

Answer (score 1):

Comments do not make it into the final exe.  I don't even think comments make it into the pdb file for a debug build.

If you have the source code that includes the comments in the directory of the exe, open the exe in olly, click the view menu then click source, this will open the source file with your comments and all.

99% of the time, what you write in your source file, is what olly shows, unless you are using a lot of macros.